# Bare Wire unattached

Tags: electrical

My bare wire from the ceiling fan became unattached from group of wires from junction box.  How do I fix and or do I need that one for a ground.  Can I use the screws connected to junction box.

[image]

Comment: If it is a completely bare wire, not just bare at the end, then it is ground and can be connected to the screw in the box or to other bare ground wires.  Have the breaker off because live power is on the other wires(blacks, reds).

Comment: Just make sure to remove any paint from the bare wire at the contact point so it makes a good electrical connection.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding so quickly.